# Infinite ways to represent $\pi$ as product of nested square roots of $2$ and $2^n$ and odd numbers

Tags: geometry, pi, nested-radicals

Polygon inscribed in a circle leads to famous infinite product by Viete's formula.[here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula)
One way to represent that as infinite nested radical of 2 as follows

$$\pi = \lim_{n\to\infty}2^n \times \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...}}}}}$$ being total number of '2's inside the nested square roots is 'n'

After some manipulation in numbers some interesting findings I'm able to observe as follows
$$3\pi = \lim_{n\to\infty}2^n \times \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}}}}}$$
$$5\pi = \lim_{n\to\infty}2^n \times \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}}}}}}$$

**In both these situations total number of '2's inside the nested square roots are 'n'.

As the n grows big each converge to respective multiples of $\pi$ more and more decimals**

Python code to verify my findings

```
from decimal import*

getcontext().prec = 100

# nested sqrts of 2 & $\pi$, $3\pi$,$5\pi$

b = int(input("Enter number of iterations: "))

a = Decimal(2).sqrt()

for i in range(b):
    a = Decimal(2 + a).sqrt()


a = Decimal(2 - a).sqrt()

Pi = 2 ** (b + 2) * a

print("\n\n Pi derived from Square as initial regular Polygon is:\n\n ", Pi)


a = Decimal(2).sqrt()
a = 2 - a
a = Decimal(a).sqrt()

b = int(input("Enter required number of cycles to calculate Pi: "))

for i in range(b):
    a = 2 + a
    a = Decimal(a).sqrt()

a = 2 - a
a = Decimal(a).sqrt()


Pi_3 = 2**(b+3)*a
C = Pi_3/3

print("\n\n",C)

a = Decimal(2).sqrt()
a = 2 - a
a = Decimal(a).sqrt()

a = 2 - a
a = Decimal(a).sqrt()

b = int(input("Enter required number of cycles to calculate Pi: "))


for i in range(b):
    a = 2 + a
    a = Decimal(a).sqrt()

#print("\n\n",a)

a = 2 - a

a = Decimal(a).sqrt()

Pi_5 = 2**(b+4)*a
C = Pi_5/5

print("\n\n",C)
# for practical purposes I have divided by 3 & 5 respectively (next to regular derivation by Viete's method) to get the value of $\pi$
```

Viete's formula is provable by geometry i.e. square becoming octagon then 16gon and so on ...

> **Is there any way to prove above 2 formulas by geometric shapes or some other methods? Are there similar infinite ways like those above?(with the help of nested square roots of 2 apart from equilateral triangle, regular Pentagon). Please comment. Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to [formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula#Related_formulas), related to Viète's formula, in  your formulas is considered a limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^n\sqrt{2-a_n}$, where $a_n=\sqrt{2+a_{n-1}}$ with the initial conditions
$a_2=-\sqrt{2}$ for the first sequence and $a_3=-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}$ for the second. Assuming $a_{n-1}=2\cos x_{n-1}$ for $x_{n-1}\in [0,\pi]$, we obtain $a_n=2\cos\tfrac {x_{n-1}}{2}$. Putting $x_n=\tfrac {x_{n-1}}2$ for all sufficiently big $n$, we obtain

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^n\sqrt{2-a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^n \sqrt{2-2\cos x_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^{n+1} \sin x_{n+1}.$$

For the first sequence we have $a_2=2\cos\tfrac{3\pi}4$, so $x_2=\tfrac{3\pi}4$ and

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^n\sqrt{2-a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^{n+1} \sin \left(\tfrac{3\pi}4\cdot \frac 1{2^{n-1}}\right)=3\pi.$$

For the second sequence we have $a_3=2\cos x_3=-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}<0$. So $x_3\in \left(\tfrac {\pi}2, \pi\right) $ and
$4\cos^2 x_3=2-\sqrt{2}$. Thus $2\cos 2x_3=-\sqrt{2}$ and so $2x_3=\tfrac {5\pi}4$ and

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^n\sqrt{2-a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^{n+1} \sin \left(\tfrac{5\pi}8\cdot \frac 1{2^{n-2}}\right)=5\pi.$$

Comment: The process goes like this. If n = 4, it will be like this. $3\pi = 2^4\times \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}}}$. If n = 5, then it will be $3\pi = 2^5\times \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}}}}$. This goes on. As the n becomes big, the result converges to $3\pi$. Similarly for $5\pi$, if n = 5, then it will be as follows $5\pi = 2^5\times \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}}}}$. And if if n = 6, then it will be as follows $5\pi = 2^6\times \sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}}}}}$. When this computation done with increasing n it converges to $5\pi$.

Comment: $\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}= 2\cos(\frac{3\pi}{8})$ and $\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}}= 2\cos(\frac{5\pi}{16})$. Is it possible to check this relationship?

Comment: @SivakumarKrishnamoorthi I fixed my error, thanks.

Comment: @SivakumarKrishnamoorthi $$2\cos\tfrac {3\pi}8=\sqrt{2+2\cos 2\cdot \tfrac {3\pi}8}=\sqrt{2+2\cos \left(\pi-\tfrac {\pi}4\right)}=
\sqrt{2-2\cos \tfrac {\pi}4}=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}.$$

$$2\cos\tfrac {5\pi}{16}=\sqrt{2+2\cos 2\cdot \tfrac {5\pi}{16}}=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+2\cos 2\cdot \tfrac {5\pi}8}}=
\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-2\cos \tfrac {\pi}4}}=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}.$$

Comment: Still more interesting is $7\pi$ = $\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^n\cdot\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...(n-4)terms\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}}}}}$ and $15\pi$ = $\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^n\cdot\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...(n-5)terms\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt2}}}}}}}$ etc. You can verify with programming. We can get all odd numbers associated with $\pi$ with varying permutations and combinations of nested square roots of 2 at the end of the radical. Can you please explain the last steps in your explanation, how did you get $3\pi$ and $5\pi$?

Comment: @SivakumarKrishnamoorthi The basic idea is $\lim_{x\to 0}\tfrac {\sin x}{x}=0$, so $\lim_{m\to\infty} m\sin\tfrac km=k$.

Comment: @SivakumarKrishnamoorthi I guess by induction with respect to $m$ it can be easily proved that a number $a_m=\sqrt{2\pm\sqrt{2 \dots\pm \sqrt{2}}}$, where are $m-1$ $2$’s equals $2\cos\frac k{2^{m+1}}$, where $k<2^{m+1}$ is  an odd natural number (and, maybe, even, conversly: for each such $k$ we have $2\cos\frac k{2^{m+1}}=\sqrt{2\pm\sqrt{2 \dots\pm \sqrt{2}}}$ for some choice of signs). Then given a recurrence $a_n=\sqrt{2+a_{n-1}}$ for each $n>m$, similarly to the proofs in the answer we can show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^n\sqrt{2-a_n}=k\pi.$

Comment: Yes. I agree with you ( for some choice of signs ). You may clearly observe that for leftward movement of __single $'-'$ sign on $m^{th}$ term, we get the result predictably $2^m-1\cdot \pi$.__ The 'm' is on left side of $'-'$ in the terminal part of nested square roots of 2. Thank you very much for excellent effort and answering. I got much more enlightened

Comment: @SivakumarKrishnamoorthi I guess you mean $(2^{m+1}-1)\pi$ and $m$ $2$'s at the right side.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. So we have to apply $\lim_{n \to \infty} n\cdot\frac{\sin\pi}{n} = \pi $ where $\pi$ inside the sine function to consider as 180°. So we have to start from the right side of nested square roots of 2, first to evaluate the cosine function, then go on to get the cosine value and the last one is taking the sine function which becomes the chord of polygon of 'n' sides.The steps make us to get the side length of the polygon, when multipled by n giving rise to half circumference which in unit circle, it is $\pi$. This is my understanding. Thank you very much.